# keep Ratio in full screen - Extract Ratio from a movie (mp4) flash player

Tags: actionscript-3

This is what i'm trying to do , get the Ratio 4:3 9:16 etc from an mp4 movie (h264) so when ill open it in fullscreen using a flash player / action script 3 it will still keep the ratio.

regards

Answer (score 0):

there is height and width varibles in the metadata recieved from loaded movies, divide one by the other to get the ratio of the video.

[livedocs example](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000267.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you are using flex: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/NetConnection.html

(see example at bottom of page)